# How to get the result table by parsing column values?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where one column (DateList, varchar(4000)) contains the list of date-time values as strings. It looks as following:

```
2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00 2014-09-29 19:00
```

How can I get the result table with the same structure, but the DateList column should have the values in some range:

```
dateItem >= minDate and dateItem <= maxDate
```

It could be the stored procedure.

THE CODE I'VE USED:

```
declare @sString VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @SplitChar CHAR(1)
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @DateLength INT 
DECLARE @XMLString XML

SET @SplitChar = ','
SET @Count = 1      
SET @DateLength = 17

SELECT @sString = DateList from T_Action where ID = 44404
PRINT @sString

WHILE @Count <= Len(@sString) / 17 - 1
BEGIN
  SET @sString = STUFF(@sString, @DateLength, 0, ',')

  SET @DateLength = 17 + @DateLength + 1
  SET @Count = @Count + 1
END

--Use XML to extract the Date.
SET @XMLString = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@sString,@SplitChar,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

CREATE TABLE #Temp (DateVal VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #Temp (DateVal)
SELECT DateValue 
FROM (SELECT T.c.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS DateValue FROM @XMLString.nodes('/root/s') T(c)) AS Temp  
WHERE DateValue BETWEEN '2014-09-27' AND '2014-09-30'

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' ' + DateVal AS DateVal FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') 
AS ExpectedResult

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temp', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Temp;
GO
```

[image: The screen shot]

Comment: make the dates as  comma separated and populate as table , filter that table with your date range and repopulate as comma separated single column

Comment: I can't use comma separated method. I should use it as is.

Comment: Is the DateList string a timeline? I mean the date on the left will alwayws be smaller then the date from the right side?

Comment: @CiucaS: Yes. But, there are not timeline values only. Some dates are as timeline, but there could be single dates as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It take longer time to figure out the Expected result.

I think your requirement is to show a column of string having dates between Min and Max dates from a column of string having dates.

Run the below stored procedure and pass the string of dates, min and max dates.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDate (@sString VARCHAR(4000), @MINDate DATETIME, @MaxDate DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @SplitChar CHAR(1)
     DECLARE @Count INT
     DECLARE @DateLength INT 
     DECLARE @XMLString XML

     SET @SplitChar = ','
     SET @Count = 1      
     SET @DateLength = 17
     SET @sString = RTRIM(@sString) + ' '

    WHILE @Count <= Len(@sString) / 17 - 1
     BEGIN
          SET @sString = STUFF(@sString, @DateLength, 0, ',')

          SET @DateLength = 17 + @DateLength + 1
          SET @Count = @Count + 1
     END

    --Use XML to extract the Date.
    SET @XMLString = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@sString,@SplitChar,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

    CREATE TABLE #Temp (DateVal VARCHAR(20))

    INSERT INTO #Temp (DateVal)
       SELECT DateValue 
       FROM (SELECT T.c.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS DateValue FROM @XMLString.nodes('/root/s') T(c)) AS Temp  
       WHERE DateValue BETWEEN @MINDate AND @MaxDate

    SELECT LTRIM((SELECT DateVal AS DateVal FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) 
    AS ExpectedResult
END
```

To execute the Stored procedure.

```
EXEC GetDate '2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00 2014-09-29 19:00', '2014-09-27 19:00', '2014-09-28 19:00'

Param 1 : String of dates.
Param 2 : Min date.
Param 3 : Max date.

ExpectedResult                                     
----------------------------------------------------
2014-09-27 19:00  2014-09-28 19:00
```

Comment: I've tried your code as normal query (not stored procedure) and fill out sString in this way: SELECT sString = DateList from T_Action where ID = 44404, that is I've used the table with real data. But, I've got ExpectedResult = NULL. When I print the content of DateList column (PRINT sString), I've got all dates one below another, not as long string of dates. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Post the content of the SELECT sString = DateList from T_Action where ID = 44404. Query. and min and max dates.

Comment: 2014-09-26 19:00
2014-09-27 19:00
2014-09-28 19:00
2014-09-29 19:00
2014-09-30 19:00
2014-10-15 19:00
2014-10-16 19:00
2014-10-17 19:00
2014-10-18 19:00
2014-10-19 19:00
2014-10-22 19:00
2014-10-23 19:00
2014-10-24 19:00
2014-10-25 19:00
2014-10-26 19:00
2014-11-11 19:00
2014-11-12 19:00
2014-11-13 19:00
2014-11-14 19:00
2014-11-15 19:00
2014-11-25 19:00
2014-11-26 19:00
2014-11-27 19:00
2014-11-28 19:00
2014-11-29 19:00

Comment: But, as I said, it looks different in MS SQL Server Management Studio. All dates are one below another.

Comment: Please, take a look at the code I've used in the original post at top.

Comment: You can take a look at the screen shot in the original post to see how it looks like.

Comment: I updated my Stored procedure. Check with it and update your status.

Comment: I've tried this:

declare sString VARCHAR(4000)
declare MINDate DATETIME
declare MaxDate DATETIME
SELECT sString = DateList from T_Action where ID = 44404
SET MINDate = cast('2014-09-27' as DATETIME)
SET MaxDate = cast('2014-09-30' as DATETIME)
EXEC GetDate sString, MINDate, MaxDate
But, there's an error:

Сообщение 241, уровень 16, состояние 1, процедура GetDate, строка 27
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Of course, I've used "the monkey" in front of variables.

Comment: Added the exec code as new answer. use it and update the result

Comment: Mark the ans if you find it useful. So, that others can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First convert the `dates in string to Rows` then find the `min` and `max` date

```
DECLARE @str   VARCHAR(200),
        @cnt   INT=1,
        @inter INT = 17 --length of a single date in the string

SELECT @str = '2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00 2014-09-29 19:00 2014-09-29 19:00'

WHILE @cnt <= Len(@str) / 17 - 1
  BEGIN
      SELECT @str = Stuff (@str, @inter, 0, ',')

      SET @inter =17 + @inter + 1
      SET @cnt+=1
  END

PRINT @str

SELECT Min(col) MIN_DATE,
       Max(col) MAX_DATE
FROM  (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')))) col
       FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@str, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
              CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @sString VARCHAR(4000)
 DECLARE @MINDate DATETIME 
 DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME

 SET @sString = '2014-09-26 19:00 2014-09-27 19:00 2014-09-28 19:00 2014-09-29 19:00 2014-09-30 19:00 2014-10-15 19:00 2014-10-16 19:00 2014-10-17 19:00 2014-10-18 19:00 2014-10-19 19:00 2014-10-22 19:00 2014-10-23 19:00 2014-10-24 19:00 2014-10-25 19:00 2014-10-26 19:00 2014-11-11 19:00 2014-11-12 19:00 2014-11-13 19:00 2014-11-14 19:00 2014-11-15 19:00 2014-11-25 19:00 2014-11-26 19:00 2014-11-27 19:00 2014-11-28 19:00 2014-11-29 19:00'
 SET @MINDate = '2014-09-27'
 SET @MaxDate = '2015-09-28'

 EXEC GetDate @sString, @MINDate, @MaxDate
```

Run and update your result.

Comment: There's an error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, procedure GetDate, Line 27
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I've get sString in this way:

SELECT sString = DateList from T_Action where ID = 44404

Comment: Is that the exact above query works without using  SELECT sString = DateList from T_Action where ID = 44404. Had you changed the SP.

Comment: Everything is the same, except for: SET @sString = ..., because I use real data from database table.

Comment: If I use your test code there are 2 spaces between resulting dates. How to make it to be with one space?

Comment: SELECT STUFF((SELECT DateVal AS DateVal FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') 
        AS ExpectedResult    remove the space (SELECT ' ' + DateVal) in the sqery.

Comment: I already tried to remove that space, but in that case "2" at the beginning is mising in first date.

Comment: SELECT (SELECT DateVal AS DateVal FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        AS ExpectedResult   - Stuff is no needed when we remove (' '). That only made that trouble.

Comment: There is a space in front of whole list of dates now.

Comment: SELECT LTRIM((SELECT DateVal AS DateVal FROM #Temp FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) 
        AS ExpectedResult . Use LTRIM. These are all  basics.

Comment: OK. It works with hard coded dates, but it doesn't with real data.

Comment: Try comparing the data with Hard coded and select query

Comment: They are the same. The error is: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I figured out what was the issue. The dates in the table were written in Russian. They looks as normal numbers, but it's not the same. When I updated the column with the same dates in English, it works fine.

Comment: Got it. After long struggle we made it.